# How to click a href which contains only a half of the full url using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, scrape

I can find the element needed to be click using selenium. But the problem is the href attribute only contains part of the full link.

For example the website is `https://vietstock.vn`

The element is one of these:
`pages = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//div[@class='owl-stage']//div[@class='single_post_text']")`

Each element is something like this:
`<a href="/2022/08/quy-dau-tu-tiep-tuc-giao-dich-tram-lang-3358-989801.htm" title="..." class="fontbold">Quỹ đầu tư tiếp tục giao dịch trầm lắng</a>`

How can I click the link with full URL as `https://vietstock.vn/2022/08/quy-dau-tu-tiep-tuc-giao-dich-tram-lang-3358-989801.htm`

Answer (score 0):

Well, after googling around, I found a solution for my own question. But honestly, I don't know the reason:

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Which `element` is the element with `href` link I just extracted.